# Disappearing bucket, how to investigate

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project for a client and a couple of weeks ago most of the content "disappeared".

Images and videos are routed through FileStack (a file processing service) but actually stored on Google Cloud Storage in one bucket.

On the day in question everything was working, and then everything stopped working. When we investigated it turned out that the bucket FileStack was pointing to was non-existent, so we created a new bucket with the same name and everything magically worked itself out.

Now my question is, where did all the files from the disappeared bucket go? Is it possible to get them back? Is it possible to figure out what happened?

I have extensively reviewed the audit log in the Activity tab and it shows zero activity for the bucket in question. Is there anywhere else we can investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object is deleted, it's deleted from the system and there isn't any option to recover it [1]. You can prevent this behavior by using object versioning [2]. And to get a better overview of the activity in Cloud Storage you can enable the "Data Access logs" [3].

About the reason why the objects has disappeared, as a first workaround you can review if there's an Object Lifecycle enabled [4].

1. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects
2. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning
3. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs
4. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Can you please send email to gs-team@google.com, noting the bucket name and an example object name from that bucket, along with the last time you were successfully able to access that bucket/object? Doing it that way will avoid exposing these names on the public forum. Please mention my name in the message, so I will get it and can investigate.

Thanks,

Mike Schwartz
GCS Team

Comment: Thanks Mike,  I'm getting a "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)" when bounce from sending to gcs-team@google.com

Comment: Sorry Joshua - the correct address is gs-team@google.com (I updated it in the answer above)

Comment: Thanks Mike we actually opted to buy the Google Gold support so I just submitted a ticket there. Appreciate your help,